# $\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

How to prove that the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)$ is positive ?

Thanks

Comment: Since each $1-\frac{1}{2n^2}$ is $>0$?

Comment: @awllower it's an infinite product.

Comment: So it remains to prove the limit exists, and I think you should specify this.

Comment: Even if the limit exists, it could be 0.

Comment: @awllower No he doesn't. The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice this.

Comment: Total lack of context. For example, do you know any method to prove that any infinite product is positive?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Only the lower limit is a problem. Look e.g. at the product for $n\geq 2$, you could prove:
$$ \prod_{n\geq 2} (1-\frac{1}{2 n^2}) \geq  \prod_{n\geq 2} (1-\frac{1}{ n^2})=\prod_{n\geq 2} \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{ n \cdot n}=\frac12$$
(the last being a telescopic product). So your product is $\geq \frac14$.

Answer (score 1):

Just prove the associated log series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\Bigl(1-\frac1{2n^2}\Bigr)$$
converges. Observe the general term of this series 
$$\log\Bigl(1-\frac1{2n^2}\Bigr)\sim_\infty -\frac1{2n^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{N \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}}$:

\begin{align}
\prod_{n = 1}^{N}\pars{1 - {1 \over 2n^{2}}} & =
\prod_{n = 1}^{N}{2\pars{n - \root{2}/2}\pars{n + \root{2}/2} \over 2n^{2}} =
{\pars{1 - \root{2}/2}^{\overline{N}}\pars{1 + \root{2}/2}^{\overline{N}} \over \pars{N!}^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\Gamma\pars{N + 1 - \root{2}/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - \root{2}/2}N!}\,
{\Gamma\pars{N + 1 + \root{2}/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + \root{2}/2}N!}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{1 - \root{2}/2}\Gamma\pars{\root{2}/2}\root{2}/2}\,
{\pars{N - \root{2}/2}! \over N!}\,{\pars{N + \root{2}/2}! \over N!}
\\[5mm] & =
{\root{2} \over \pi/\sin\pars{\pi\root{2}/2}}\,
{\pars{N - \root{2}/2}! \over N!}\,{\pars{N + \root{2}/2}! \over N!}
\end{align}

---

Note that
\begin{align}
{\pars{N + \alpha}! \over N!} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{\root{2\pi}\pars{N + \alpha}^{N + \alpha + 1/2}\expo{-\pars{N + \alpha}} \over
{\root{2\pi}N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N}}} =
{N^{N + \alpha + 1/2}\pars{1 + \alpha/N}^{N + \alpha + 1/2}\expo{-\alpha} \over
N^{N + 1/2}}
\\[5mm] & \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
N^{\alpha}
\end{align}

> such that

\begin{align}
\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{1 - {1 \over 2n^{2}}} & =
\bbx{{\root{2}\sin\pars{\sqrt{2}\,\pi/2} \over \pi}} \approx 0.3582
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/08/0001/) $\sin z$ can be expressed by an infinite product, namely

$$\sin z=z \prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi ^2 n^2}\right)$$
Thus for $z=\dfrac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}$ we get
$$\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\dfrac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\,\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{1}{2 n^2}\right)$$
hence $$\prod _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\frac{1}{2 n^2}\right)=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\dfrac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}}\approx 0.358$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The exact value of such product can be derived from the Weierstrass product for the sine function, as already shown by Raffaele. As an alternative approach, we may notice that
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4}\prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{4n^4}\right)\geq\frac{1}{4}\prod_{n\geq 2}\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n} $$
where the last product is a telescopic product:
$$ \prod_{n=2}^{N}\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{N+1}{2N}\stackrel{N\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{2} $$
hence it follows that the value of the original product is $\color{red}{\large\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}}$.
Such lower bound turns out to be pretty accurate.

Answer (score -2):

$1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}<1-\dfrac{1}{2n^2}<\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^2$,So you can see Its limit exist.

Sorry For I cannot use LaTex and My poor English.